# All Images on wordpress site broken

Tags: images, uploads, links

Recently one of my live wordpress site's broke. And no it was not because of an update since I haven't updated recently (only to 3.1 but then everything worked)

For some reason all images now look like this: example.nl/index.php?aam_media=3470. And I cannot acces it.

Also when uploading new images they also are instantly broken what could be the cause of this.

Live version with image error: http://fysergo.nl
Live other site with almost same setup & plugins but not broken: http://spektakelzwijndrecht.nl

So does anyone has any clues? I hope I have provided enough information, I can give additional information as needed. I have contacted support but so far no luck with them.

Comment: It looks like you are using the "Advanced Access Manager" plugin – [this support thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/aam-changing-all-image-urls-to-aam_media) suggests there was a problem with a recent update - try following the instructions to disable it's image handling to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to AAM (Advanced Access Manager) plugin. You have different options to fix the issue.

```
1) Disable AAM Media Manager plugin
2) You can changes AAM Media Manager plugin version
3) If you do not want AAM to handle your website images, Go to the following file /advanced-access-manager/extension/AAM_Media_Manager/extension.php and find

private $_skip = false;

change above to

private $_skip = TRUE;
```

Please refer this link for more details.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/aam-changing-all-image-urls-to-aam_media

Comment: Yes Thank you! this was the solution that worked for me, I still find it strange that no other site was affected but I suppose they did not do the update yet?